# state of std::atomic_shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, atomic, c++20

I'm trying to wrap a std::shared_ptr inside a std::atomic. A trivial example would be:

```
std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<int>> ptr{std::make_shared<int>(42)};
```

When compiling with `clang++ -std=c++2a -stdlib=libc++ test.cc` I get following error:

```
_Atomic cannot be applied to type 'std::__1::shared_ptr<int>' which is not trivially copyable
```

[CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2) suggests that in C++20, std::atomic's constructor supports std::shared_ptr.

I wanted to try [std::atomic_shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/atomic_shared_ptr) instead but couldn't find the appropriate header. Neither `experimental/atomic` nor `atomic` could find the class.

Is there a standard supported way to wrap std::shared_ptr in std::atomic in C++20?

**Update**

As @NathanOliver suggested, for now I can use the [atomic_* function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) overloads without wrapping the shared_ptr in an atomic.

Comment: I think it has yet to be implemented in clang. See [here](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).

Comment: [According to cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/Template:cpp/compiler_support/20), MSVC is the only implementation that has yet implemented atomic `shared_ptr`.

Comment: ah bummer, feel like it's been a while since I first heard of it...

Comment: It's deprecated in C++20 because of `std::atomic_shared_ptr`, but if you need to get something working right now, there is the old way: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic

Comment: Note, [atomic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) `shared_ptr<T>` operations are "atomic" but are not lock-free. In fact they require [a global mutex (pool of global mutexes)](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/shared_ptr.cc#L35). `atomic_shared_ptr` is designed to at least keep associated mutex within atomic_shared_ptr object itself.